# Nest.js socket.io ping/pong between server/client

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I use nestjs back-end and Vuejs front with socket.io, and need to see if user "isAlive".

I tried ping server side and pong client side, but server side nothing do...

Server side (nest.js)

```js
@WebSocketGateway({
  pingTimeout: 100
})
export class LockGateway {

  @SubscribeMessage('ping')
    ping(socket: Socket, data: any) {
      console.log(`Ping with ${data.toString()}`);
      socket.emit('pong', (response) => {
        console.log(`Response from client side : ${response.toString()}`);
      });
  }
}
```

client side (vuejs / ts)

```js
this.socket.on('pong', () => {
        console.log('PONG I m alive');
        this.socket.emit('ping', 'I m alive');
      });
```

in client side, i have all console.log in pong, but on server side, have nothing :/

Comment: Did you try to up the ping timeout, maybe the time without the pong is above 100

Comment: `pingTimeout` nothing change, i changed my strategy, and testing client side inactivity with `addEventListener` and `window.setTimeout(this.doInactive, this.timeoutInMiliseconds);`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "ping" for `SubscribeMessage`. Try replacing it with another event name.

Comment: Hey welcome! Your answer could use some more information. Perhaps add an example code snippet using a valid event name. Or link/doc quote as to why ping can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

WORK Solution :

Client side :

```
this.socket.on('isAvailable', () => {
  this.socket.emit('keepAlive', socketClient.userUid);
});
```

Server side:

```
@SubscribeMessage('join')
join(socket: Socket, data: any) {
if (data.userUid != null) {
  this.userUid = data.userUid;
}
if (data.userUid && data.userUid !== ANONYMOUS_USER) {
  this.keepAliveInterval = setInterval(() => {
    socket.emit('isAvailable');
  }, RETRY_EACH);
  this.setOfflineTimeout(socket, data.userUid);
}
```

}